# How do I make it so I can add multiple inputs to a function and those inputs are added to a list as separate elements?

Tags: python

Here is my code so far.

```
myUniqueList = []

def myFunction(input):
    if input in myUniqueList:
        return False
    else:
        myUniqueList.append(input)
        print(myUniqueList)
        return True
print(myFunction(2))
```

I want to be able to have multiple inputs into a myFunction and have those first checked throughout the entire list if one of those inputs is equal to another input if so, the function should return false. If not, the function should add those inputs to the list, each as a separate element, print the list and return True. I have tried using something like *args but I am just stuck.

Comment: pass a list as input and then check on those list element

Answer (score 0):

First `input` is a builtin function, I wouldn't overwrite builtins. As for checking inclusivity you can use the `in` keyword in your `if` statement. As for passing multiple arguments you can use star packing then check inclusivity using `any` if True just extend the list with args and to remove duplicates just use `dict.from_keys`:

```
myUniqueList = []

def myFunction(*args):
    if any(n in myUniqueList for n in args):
            return False
        else:
            myUniqueList.extend(dict.from_keys(args))
            print(myUniqueList)
            return True
```

Also instead of using any you can use set, it's more efficient:

```
if set(args) <= set(myUniqueList):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myUniqueList = [1 , 2]

def myFunction(*argv):
    for input in argv:
        if input in myUniqueList:
            return False
        else:
            myUniqueList.append(input)
            print(myUniqueList)
    return True

print(myFunction(2)) # False
print(myFunction(0, 4, 6)) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a python set to compare if an array has duplicate values within it and later add it to the `myUniqueList` if it doesn't already exist within it.

```
myUniqueList = []

def myFunction(arr: list):
    if len(arr) != len(set(arr)):
        return False
    else:
        [myUniqueList.append(i) if i not in myUniqueList else None for i in arr]
        print(myUniqueList)
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

This updated code lets you decide how long the input list is

```
myUniqueList = []
def myFunction(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] in myUniqueList:
            return False
        else:
            myUniqueList.append(lst[i])
    print(myUniqueList)
    return True

inputList = []
l = int(input("length of list: "))
for i in range(l):
    inputList.append(input(f"Enter element {i+1}: "))
print(myFunction(inputList))
```